# List of dates sorted from file bash

Tags: bash, list, awk, sed

I'm trying to find from a list of people all of them that they are born between certain dates. The list has this form:

**id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|joinDate|IP|browser**

and the user is giving the dates using this form:

```
./tool.sh --born-since <dateA> --born-until <dateB> -f <file>
```

*I have already tried this:*

```
bs=$2
bu=$4
sed -e '/-bs/,/bu/g' persons.dat
exit 1
```

*and this:*

```
sed -e '/^#/d' persons.dat | awk -F "|" '!( $5 in a ) {a[$5]; print $0}' | sort
exit 1
```

but I can't seem to find the right results.

Comment: If your script is just taking the configuration from fixed positional parameters, there's no point in using the options; just use `./tool.sh <dateA> <dateB> <file>`.

Comment: What is your date format?

Comment: My date format is 1970-10-28 as shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example showing how to use `getopt` to parse the options:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage="usage: $0 --born-since DATE --born-until DATE -f FILE"

temp=$(getopt -o f: --long born-since:,born-until: -n "$0" -- "$@")
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "$usage"
    exit 1
fi

eval set -- "$temp"

while :; do
    case "$1" in
        -f) file=$2 ; shift 2;;
        --born-since) bs=$2; shift 2;;
        --born-until) bu=$2; shift 2;;
        --) shift; break;;
        *) echo "internal error"; exit 1;;
    esac
done

if [[ -z $file ]]; then
    echo "error: no -f option given"
    echo "$usage"
    exit 1
fi
# TODO: other validations

awk -v since="$bs" -v until="$bu" -F "|" 'since <= $5 && $5 <= until' "$file"
```

Comment: Isn't `getopt` discouraged and `getopts` should be used instead (see, for example, [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035#getopts))?

Comment: Getopts only does short option names

Comment: Oh, I see that there are different versions - like the "GNU enhanced `getopt`" that supports everything `getopts` does plus long options. Never mind :)

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

The data:

```
$ cat foo  
id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|joinDate|IP|browser
||||2012-01-01|||
||||1970-01-01|||
```

The program:

```
$ cat script.awk
NR==1 || $5 < until && $5 > since  # print the first record and when dates fit
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -F\| -v since="2011-01-01" -v until="2014-01-01" -f script.awk foo
id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|joinDate|IP|browser
||||2012-01-01|||
```

If the dates are in above format, there is no need to parse them.

Comment: but how you add the values until and since on the program? and what's the script.awk?

Answer (score 0):

Using dateutils http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/

```
$ cat foo
||||2012-01-01|||
||||2013-01-01|||
||||1971-01-01|||
||||1970-01-01|||

$ dategrep ">=1971-01-01&&<=2012-01-01"  < foo 
||||2012-01-01|||
||||1971-01-01|||
```

And moreover `datesort`:

```
$ dategrep ">=1971-01-01&&<=2012-01-01"  < foo  | datesort
||||1971-01-01|||
||||2012-01-01|||
```

`dategrep` and `datesort` also understand `--input-format=STRING` (strftime-like format specs)

**DISCLAIMER** This does not work if you have other dates in the same line :P